# IOS background communication between apps

Tags: android, ios, android-intent

I have made two apps that can talk with each other, I did this with broadcast receiver and the intent service from android 
Info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

My question is if it also can be achieved in IOS? Which commands could I use to communicate between apps?

thanks

Comment: CloudKit can be a solution (best one I guess). Depending on type of your data to be shared between, you can use Keychain

Comment: I achieve the task with app groups... url schemes can also pass parameters... @gruntcakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finish up with app groups...

https://agostini.tech/2017/08/13/sharing-data-between-applications-and-extensions-using-app-groups/

Thanks

Comment: An answer should be more than just an external link. Links die. Include the relevant parts of the content in your answer so that the answer can stand on its own.